# How can I create a list in Sheet1 made up of selections on Sheet2 in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create a quote form that will print only the selections of interest to my prospect.  I want to list all available options (list of my services) in Sheet2 and make my selections (for example - in a list of 100 items, I select items 1, 2, 5, 14, 29, etc).  Only the selected items would display on the quote in Sheet1 with no blank spaces in between.

Does this make sense?  Does anyone know how I can eliminate all of the blank lines between the selections?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please **[edit]** your question to include what you've already tried and where you got stuck. This is kind of a "self-help" site, in that, you start and we help you when there are problems. The [help] can explain better.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LARGE(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,ROW()-1)),INDEX(Sheet2!A$1:A$100,MATCH(LARGE(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,ROW()-1),Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,0)),"")
```

that goes in A2 and gets copied all the way to D100. **But** it only works if order quantities are unique. So Fail-big time. Can you add a little image paste or just a typed mockup of your exact columns?

Comment: Questions like this that provide no specifics are tough to provide a good answer for.  Generally, it is better to ask for specifics in comments and then give a specific answer when there is enough information to do so.  SU's purpose is to compile questions and answers for reference (which is mostly external, BTW).  The questioner gets their problem solved in the process.  So addressing the questioner by name or saying you will provide a more detailed solution if they provide more information really isn't consistent with the nature of the site (another reason to wait for details).

Comment: Thus continues my education of S.O. No use disagreeing with Mods or rules (of thumb?); they are what they are. And for good reason: you don't want it to fill up with garbage. It slows everyone down and discourages ppl altogether. I do think SU should tolerate a bit more than SO. However if the OP has just a little persistence, my answer above is all he needs.

Comment: Thanks Klausnrooster.  I don't know how to "add a little image paste" so here is an example of what columns I need:

Comment: QUANTITY | SERVICE | PER ITEM | MINIMUM | AMOUNT

Comment: So the User would add the quantity for the services they need on Tab2 where all of the services are listed.  The records with a quantity would display on Tab1 which is the Order form.  The only think I don't know is how to write a formula that takes, for example, the five selected services from Tab2 and lists them on Tab1 with no blank row between.  I don't understand how to use the information you gave in the example above.  I'm not as experienced or as good at this as you and the others are.  Thanks for the help - please try to "dumb-down" any future advice :)

Comment: I figured out what SU means, but have no idea what SO or OP stands for...

Comment: SO is Stack Overflow, another StackExchange site like SU but solely programming focused. OP is Original Poster which means you! Ok, your example is enough detail for me but it's late. I shall return. Solution will involve functions LARGE or SMALL, INDEX, MATCH, maybe a few more. Maybe less!

Comment: I have never used any of those functions, but I will research them on the web and see what I can find out.  Thank you for your patience and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I corrected my original stab at a formula and it works unless the customer has the same quantity for 2 or more services. So that's a big fail. The solution is FILTER on the DATA tab of the Ribbon (not hard to find on older, pre-ribbon Excel versions either).

[image]

The clever part is that you only maintain 1 master list of services, prices, minimums. You don't use it for anything else. You "duplicate" it for every customer's/order's sheet by entering in B1:

```
= Sheet1!B1
```

where Sheet1 has the master list. You copy that formula to all B, C, D rows you need. Leave A for the Quantity and do your calculations in column E (You don't have to do "fancy" tricks to hide the zeros or error values, the filter hides them for you). You apply the filter to the customers sheets, not the master list sheet. This is so easy. My explanation is more complicated than the solution. Here is a link: [Microsoft's Intro to Filter](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Quick-start-Filter-data-by-using-an-AutoFilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Also take a look at Advanced Filter - you may prefer to copy the master list to many sheets and then use Advanced Filter's "Filter the list, in place" option (or another).

Comment: That did the trick, Klausnrooster!  Thank you for your patience and your invaluable assistance.  I hope that I can repay the favor one day, either directly to you or by assisting someone else.

Comment: Great Kip. Can you click to accept the answer please? Closes the loop so to speak.